# Child styling of specific locations div's

Tags: css, parent-child

I'm using in multiple parts of my website a shortcode to show woocommerce categories.

There are a few places where I've placed it and doesn't look so good I need to style a specific div that's included in the shortcode ("items") but only when it's under a major div "wpb_wrapper".

[image]

As you can see i would like to style "items" (to display: inline-flex;) only when it's under "wpb_wrapper".
I've tried several options but didn't work, such as:

```
@media (min-width: 991px) {
    wpb_wrapper > woocommerce > row > shop-grid > items-env > items {
        display: inline-flex;
    }
}
```

or

```
@media (min-width: 991px) {
    wpb_wrapper > items {
        display: inline-flex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to include `.` before a class name!

Comment: Add  .  before class name.

Comment: Jeez guys, what an idiot. Thanks you very much, forgot to place them....